# How to print the letters Loading... one by one in jquery or php?

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to print the letters loading one by one that delays each letter by a second. Like so

*L o a d i n g*

How can I achieve this?  Would I need timers?

Comment: Use `setTimeout`... What did ***you*** try?

Comment: Also the language name is `javascript` and **not** `jQuery`. jQuery is a javascript library

Comment: @Neal please show me an example of this

Comment: The internet has many many examples.

Comment: @user2557464 begging specific people randomly normally has the effect of _everyone_ being _less_ inclined to help you. We want to see some effort here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script should work for you. (Place it where you want the text to go).

```
<script>
  (function(D){
      var text = 'Loading';

      var scripts = D.getElementsByTagName('script');
      var this_script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];

      var container = D.createElement('span');
      this_script.parentNode.insertBefore(container, this_script);

      (function next(i){
          container.innerHTML += text[i] + ' ';
          if(++i < text.length)
              setTimeout(function(){ next(i); }, 1000);
      })(0);
  })(document);
</script>
```

Comment: Why feed the OP? Let him/her try something please...

Comment: @Neal Down vote for that?

Comment: @DJDavid98 There is no reason to answer this non-question...

Comment: I can understand the downvote, but the delete vote on my answer is a little uncalled for. I spent nearly 5 minutes writing that script! It could come in handy for others searching for the same thing too.

Comment: 5 stars thank you paulpro